# getStringExtra() works but getIntExtra() returns null

Tags: java, android

When I tried to pass a String extra over to the next activity, It works fine. When I try to pass a int like the following codes, it crashs and throws Resources$NotFoundException. I've been playing around it for few hours so I thought I can get some guidance with this.

This is the code from the activity that is passing the values with putExtra()

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent cP = new Intent("com.example.loldb.championscreen");
        int x = arg2 + 1;
        System.out.println(x);
        cP.putExtra("champNo", x);
        startActivity(cP);

    }
```

and here's the code of the receiving activity trying to getIntExtra() the data

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_champion_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    TextView cName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cname);
    int temp = intent.getIntExtra("champNo", 0);

    //int champNo = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    cName.setText(temp);


}
```

If possible I would like to get an explanation on this matter, so I can understand it a little more.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
cName.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
```

`setText` will take charactersequence. There is one that takes int value which is a resource. If not found you end up getting `ResourceNotFoundException`.

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

Takes resid which is a int.

What you need

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text)
```

Added in API level 1
Sets the string value of the TextView. TextView does not accept HTML-like formatting, which you can do with text strings in XML resource files. To style your strings, attach android.text.style.* objects to a SpannableString, or see the Available Resource Types documentation for an example of setting formatted text in the XML resource file.

Comment: Oh I thought that the one that takes int, is actually taking an int. It never got to me that It was a resource. Thanks!

Comment: @user3370206 have a look at setText @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html